# Can google apps be an alternative to outlook server with blackberry email and calendar

Tags: web-hosting, email

A client of mine is looking for hosting and email. They will be using a blackberry and outlook for both email and calendar functionality. They are used to working in an office environment where outlook server and a blackberry server work together.

Will Google apps fulfill the same roles as outlook server and does it sync well with blackberries. Will Google apps push to the blackberry new emails and calendar events?

Otherwise they would have to go with an outlook email hosting plan which is 20$ a month. Google apps is 50$ a year.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bundarr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this for some time. A BlackBerry can have [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) installed, which will synchronize emails, contacts, and calendars in both directions. It's easy to set up, and then you can forget it. The google calendars are integrated with the BB calendar, same with the contacts and the mail.

There are quite a few [mobile apps](http://www.google.com/mobile/more/) available, some of which can tie into the Google Apps account.